# Dynamically add lists as embedded document in Python pymongo mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Let’s say this represents a complex document I need to insert:

```
customer = {
  'first_name' : 'Arnold',
  'last_name' :  'Pettibone',

  'addresses': [
    'home' : {
      'street' : '1234 fake street',
      'city' :   'Anytown',
      'state' :  'OH',
      'zip' :    '12345'
    },
    'work' : {
      'street' : '742 Evergreen Terrace',
      'city' :   'Springfield',
      'state' :  'OH',
      'zip':     '12345'
    }
  ]
```

}

I have the `first_name` and `last_name` in string variables.  I have the addresses in a 2 dimensional list - many addresses, each that have 4 fields.

How can I append the list dynamically to the customer document in Python?

Here is some bad pseudo code.  I am new to Python as well as MongoDB so I am sure there is some basic Python that I am missing that would resolve this.

```
 customer = {
      'first_name' : 'Arnold',
      'last_name' :  'Pettibone',
    }
      'addresses': [
    for item in address_list:
    {
          'street' : item[0],
          'city' :   item[1],
          'state' :  item[2],
          'zip' :    item[3]
        }
      ]
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your initial setup is like this:

```
>>> first_name = 'Arnold'
>>> last_name = 'Pettibone'
>>> addresses = [['1234 fake street', 'Anytown', 'OH', '12345'],]
>>> addresses = [['1234 fake street', 'Anytown', 'OH', '12345'],
...     ['742 Evergreen Terrace', 'Springfield', 'OH', '12345']]
...
```

Then you can construct a "customer" dict like:

```
>>> customer = {
...     'first_name': first_name,
...     'last_name': last_name,
...     'addresses': [{
...         'street' : item[0],
...         'city' :   item[1],
...         'state' :  item[2],
...         'zip' :    item[3]
...      } for item in addresses]}
...
```

It turns out like this:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(customer)
{'addresses': [{'city': 'Anytown',
                'state': 'OH',
                'street': '1234 fake street',
                'zip': '12345'},
               {'city': 'Springfield',
                'state': 'OH',
                'street': '742 Evergreen Terrace',
                'zip': '12345'}],
 'first_name': 'Arnold',
 'last_name': 'Pettibone'}
```

Comment: Is there anything else I can help you with, or will you marked my answer "accepted" in Stack Overflow?